# Best way to structure database objects with multiple features and attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, attributes

I have a product model. Each product has a different feature set, and has many features.

Instead of creating a product model that lists all of it's features (since this would involve including a lot of features I do not need, and when I needed to add new features it would be difficult) my thought was to create one column that stores a "features array". So, be it this product is a laptop, and I wanted to know the screen size, I could call:

```
@laptop.features[:screen]
=> "15.6 inch"
```

The problem with this that I am not sure there is a simple and practical way to build a form that could accept various features, then map them to the array.

I found a railscast (#196) that explains there is `accepts_nested_attributes_for` built into rails that would basically have using both a Product model and Feature model and just associate the two records.

Which way would be better? Is there a common approach for this sort of problem? And is there a way to have a form in your view that would accept features? (even if they are not directly apart of the Product model's database structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go with a more flexible solution of having a has_many relationship with features.  Then you can easily call `@product.features` to get the products features and the flexibility really shines when you want to do something like assign multiple attributes to screen.  If you are throwing hashes into your database you wouldn't be able to add two attributes (easily anyways) to screen.

Say you wanted @product.features[:screen] to show IPS of TFT in the future as well as size, then you would have to have nested hashes or something else that would be really ugly to process.

Comment: I was thinking something along the same lines, and I like the points you made against hashes. However I have just a couple concerns... In terms of keeping the database concise. Won't I have a lot of columns that I am not using. Since everytime a new feature is added or needs to be added it will now be shared with every laptop whether it has it or not

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a Features table that contains the features that you want to mention for the products, probably with a type attribute. Maybe "Type: Display, Key: Size, Value: 1920x1080", or "Type: HDD, Key: Capacity, Value: 2GB". You can use the type to create 'families' of keys. You can make your keys anything you want to track, and the value is just a string.

With that Feature list built, you create a joining table/model (assignments?) that tracks which product has which features.

```
Product (id, non-feature attributes)
    has_many assignments
    has_many features, through assignments 

Feature (id, type, key, value)
    has_many assignments
    has_many products, through assignments

Assignments (id, product_id, feature_id, timestamps?)
    belongs_to product
    belongs_to feature
```

Given that you're linking a product id to a feature id, you can fiddle with your feature value text without breaking anything. Decide that "1920x1080" should be "1920px x 1080px" -- just change the feature record.